Mathematical proof: how to prove that if $xy$ and $x-y$ are both even, then $x$ and $y$ are both even for integers $x$ and $y$
I saw this question was already previously posted, but I didn't really understand the replies to the question, so I'm asking it again.

Prove that if $xy$ and $x-y$ are both even, then $x$ and $y$ are both even for integers $x$ and $y$.

There is no specific method of proof that the question asks for so it can be proved through contrapositive, contradiction, or even directly. I tried direct and contradiction, but I couldn't get far with either one.
I'm also confused about if you were to prove it via contrapositive. What would the contrapositive statement be? Because you would have to negate both halves of the statements, and I'm not sure how to negate $x$ and $y$ are both even for integers $x$ and $y$ because there are so many words that you can flip in this line (like do I change 'and', 'both' or 'even', etc.)

Please provide a link to the other question by editing your post, thank you.

The contrapositive is "If x and y are NOT both even, then xy and x-y are NOT both even". You can prove this by considering cases of $(x, y) = $(even, odd), (odd, even), (odd, odd). $\quad$ You have to flip the entire statement - See where I added in the word NOT. Note that "Not (A and B)" is "Not A or Not B"

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: if $x-y$ is even, what parity combinations can $x,,y$ have?

How about brute force?  Either x and y are both even, they are both odd, or one is odd and one is even.  How do each of those cases reflect on your proposition?

Given that $xy$ is even, and $x-y$ is even, assume that $x$ is odd, and show that this leads to a contradiction.
Notice that $xy=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. This can only happen if $y$ is even, that is $y=2j$ for some $j\in\mathbb{Z}$. But then we also know that $x-y = 2m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Therefore, $x-2j=2m$ which means $$x=2m+2j,$$ or, $x=2(m+j)=2\ell$ where $\ell=m+j$ and $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$. This means that $x$ is even. But that is a contradiction. You can do the same for $y$ as well.
Edit:
More rigorously, we have some premises, $P_1: xy$ is even, $P_2: x-y$ is even, and we introduce a third premise $P_3:x$ is odd. We then show that with these three premises we can derive $\neg P_3$. Which means we have derived $P_3\to\neg P_3$. Now $P_3\to\neg P_3$ tautologically implies $\neg P_3$. Therefore $P_3$ has to be false.

More rigorously, we have some premises, $P_1: xy$ is even, $P_2: x-y$ is even, and we introduce a third premise $P_3: x$ is odd. We then show that with these three premises we can derive $\neg P_3$. Which means we have derive $P_3\rightarrow\neg P_3$. Now $P_3\rightarrow\neg P_3$ is always false, and this can only happen when $P_3$ itself is false.

$P_3 \to \neg P_3$ isn’t always false.

Yes, my bad. I should have said that $P_3\rightarrow\neg P_3$ tautologically implies $\neg P_3$. Therefore $P_3$ has to be false.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here .

Mridul, consider adding your first comment (corrected per your second comment) directly in your answer. Nice work.

If $xy$ is even, it must have a factor of $2$, atleast; assume WLOG that $y$ is even, then $xy=2xk$, where $k = \frac{y}{2}$, is an integer.
Since $x - y$ is even, we have $x - y = 2l$, where $l$ is an integer.
or, $x = 2l + y$.
or, $x = 2l + 2k$.
i.e, $x = 2(l + k)$, both $l$ and $k$ are integers.
So, $x$ is also even.
We already said that $y$ is even.
We have: both $x$ and $y$ are even integers.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

All the answers here proves your statement and are completely fine. Let me elucidate a little on your doubt about contraposition.
Your statement is

If $xy$ and $x−y$ are both even, then $x$ and $y$ are both even.

Let's look at it as a logical statement. Let $$P:\text{$xy$ is even}$$ $$Q:\text{$x-y$ is even}$$ $$R:\text{$x$ is even}$$ $$S:\text{$y$ is even}$$
Then you want to show that $P\land Q\Rightarrow R\land S$. The contrapositive of this is $\lnot(R\land S)\Rightarrow \lnot(P\land Q)$ which on breaking the nots using De-Morgan gives $(\lnot R)\lor(\lnot S)\Rightarrow (\lnot P)\lor(\lnot Q)$ which in plain english reads

If $x$ is odd or $y$ is odd, then $xy$ is odd or $x-y$ is odd.

Beautiful. We can try proving this now. Note that statements of the form $A\lor B\Rightarrow C$ can be proven as $A\Rightarrow C$ and $B\Rightarrow C$ (try to prove this using logic if you want!).

If $x$ is odd, then $y$ can be two things : either even or odd. If it is even, then $xy$ is even and $x-y$ is odd. Thus $xy$ is odd or $x-y$ is odd is true. If it is odd, then...
If $y$ is odd, then $x$ can be two things : either even or odd. If it is even, then $xy$ is even and $x-y$ is odd. Thus $xy$ is odd or $x-y$ is odd is true. If it is even, then...

(I'll let you finish the arguments).
Thus in both cases we satisfy the implication holds and thus the statement's contrapositive is true, and hence the statement itself is true.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here .

@BillDubuque None of the answers in the suggested duplicate question really address OP's confusion regarding contrapositivity of this statement.

Of course, there are also plenty of duplicates for that too.
